# Book of short stories(?) - Ghost turns things inside out

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I'm looking for a book I read when I was younger that I used to absolutely love (2000 - 2010); I'm pretty sure it was a collection of short stories. I grew up in the UK, and will most likely have read this in a school library. I can only remember vague details about two of the stories:

First story: A man wins the lottery, then he decides to start giving away free money. He starts giving people more and more each time as they are more and more polite/grateful. As the line of people lining up grows so does the amount he gives, ending up at like $200 each time. People are camping for days just to get the money. When he eventually runs out the people who have been waiting for days lynch him by drowning in a well(?).

Second story: A kid goes to an abandoned house and meets a ghost who tries to scare him by turning things inside out (a sausage then a watermelon?). Unfortunately for the ghost this kid is fearless, literally never scared. The ghost must pass a scariness exam before a ghost inspector to be allowed to leave the house (or move on from being a ghost?). The story ends when the ghost gets super desperate and says the incantation for turning the kid inside out (incantation is something like BLAN-TANG-object-KABLOOIE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second story is probably Paul Jennings's "Inside Out", which can be found in *[Unbelievable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbelievable_(short_story_collection))* and *[Inside Out: And More Stories to Twist Your Insides](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000737AQC)*.

[image: Unbelievable]

> A boy who is a fan of horror films and isn't scared of anything leaves his sister at home alone for a night because she has stolen his rented scary movie. He decides to rest for a night at an old house, but it turns out to be the home of a student spook who has an upcoming exam; if the student fails his exam to scare the boy, he'll be frozen for a whole year until the next exam. Was later loosely adapted as an episode of *Round The Twist*.

The one about the man giving away money may be "The Busker":

> A boy needs money because he wants to go on a date. When his father refuses, he spends the night to find a job so he can get the money. However, he meets an old man who tells him a story of how he worked as a busker when he was younger with his only friend, a little dog named Tiny. He becomes so desperate for friendship that when he wins the lotto and becomes rich, he tries give the money to people so they will like him. Too late, he realizes that money can never buy true friendship, and that he never appreciated the only real friend he ever had.

I found this by searching for *short story ghost turns things "inside out" to scare kid*

Comment: Yes this is it! The book was Unbelievable as I recognise all the other stories mentioned in the Wiki link. Thank you so much this has been bothering me on and off for ages :)